# jquery tabs with ajax, how to change url

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

I'm currently using Jquery Tabs with ajax to load external content. (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

I also have the code below to show which tab is being shown in the URL:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: function (event, ui) {
                window.location.hash = ui.panel.id;
            }
        });

    });
});
```

I wanted to know if you are able to change how the link is shown? Right now default shows "page.htm l#undefined", tab 1 shows "page.htm l#ui-tabs-1", tab 2 shows "page.htm l#ui-tabs-2", etc...

Is there a way where I can custom name it? and have the default automatically show tab 1 in the url?

For example "page.html#account"

I can't seem to find the correct resources or I'm looking in the wrong place...

Answer (score 0):

Just change your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="accounts.html" data-hash="account">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="other.html" data-hash="other">Proin dolor</a></li>
</ul>
```

and your javascript:

```
activate: function(event,ui){
  window.location.hash = $(event.currentTarget).data('hash');
}
```

For some reason I don't know, data is not detected, try:

```
window.location.hash = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-hash');
```

You could also use `load`, receives a function executed after a remote tab is loaded. `activate` is receives a function executed after a tab transition animation has finished.

Comment: I can't do thy because the content will be coming from external pages, is there no way to go around it?

Comment: print `console.log(ui.panel.id)` in browser, if that's the value appearing in hash, you can just do `location.hash = event.currentTarget.href`

Comment: I actually tried your initial suggestion and although #undefined doesn't appear anymore, but when I click to the other tabs are still showing "#ui-tabs-2", "#ui-tabs-3". Doesn't seem to be reading the data-hash that was given..

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, turns out its already supported: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Ajax_mode
by just adding title="" to the "a" tag...

Comment: That link doesn't go to an "Ajax_mode" section any more.  Do you know if this still works in the newest version of jQuery UI?  I can't get it to work.

I'm using this to add the hash:
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        location.hash = ui.newPanel.selector;
    },

Comment: Found out how.  I just use the aria-controls attribute on the li element to custom name a tab loaded via ajax